# Why can't i find Panel repeater item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, repeater, panel

I keep getting an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error when I try to find a `Panel` control within a `Repeater`. But the other controls are all found fine? Can anyone see what is wrong here?

This is how I'm selecting the control:

```
Panel pnlSubCategories = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlSubCategories");
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInnerCategories" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCategories_OnItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
       <li id="liCategory" runat="server">
           <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCategory" runat="server">
                <span><asp:Literal ID="litCategory" runat="server" Visible="true" /></span>
                <asp:Image ID="imgMan" runat="server" Visible="false" /></asp:HyperLink>

                <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubCategories" runat="server" Visible="false">
                  <ul>
                     <asp:Repeater ID="rptSubCategories" runat="server" Visible="false" OnItemDataBound="rptSubCategories_OnItemDataBound">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                        <li id="liSubCategory" runat="server">
                         <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSubCategory" runat="server">
                          <span><asp:Literal ID="litSubCategory" runat="server" /></span></asp:HyperLink>
                        </li>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:Repeater>
                  </ul>
                 </asp:Panel>
        </li>            
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
{
     Category category = (Category)e.Item.DataItem;
     HyperLink lnkCategory = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("lnkCategory");
     Literal litCategory = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litCategory");
     HtmlGenericControl liCategory = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("liCategory");
     Image imgMan = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgMan");

     Panel pnlSubCategories = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlSubCategories");
     Repeater subCategories = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptSubCategories");

     if (category.ParentCategoryId != 0)
     {
          pnlSubCategories.Visible = true; //Getting the error on this line
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit* What I've tried so far:

`Panel pnlSubCategories = (Panel)liCategory.Controls[0].FindControl("pnlSubCategories");`

`Panel pnlSubCategories = (Panel)liCategory.Controls[1].FindControl("pnlSubCategories");`

`Panel pnlSubCategories = (Panel)Page.FindControl("pnlSubCategories");`

`Panel pnlSubCategories = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlSubCategories");`

But I still get the same error...

Edit 2*

I commented out the `Panel` control and it can't find the `Repeater subCategories` underneath it either? Something has gone horribly wrong here.......

Edit 3*

[Code Behind](http://pastebin.com/H6ms8x71) and [Markup](http://pastebin.com/xeKZ0BGX)

Comment: you are giving wrong index, correct index is 3 use this pnlSubCategories = (Panel)liCategory.Controls[3].FindControl("pnlSubCategories");

Comment: I've tried with a multitude of indexes and it still can't find it...

Comment: ok, then dont give index just use `Panel pnlSubCategories = (Panel)liCategory.FindControl("pnlSubCategories");` hope that it will work

Comment: I've already tried that one too. No luck.

Comment: There are no other repeaters using the same event.

Comment: Ok. The reason I asked was that your repeater is called `rptInnerCategories` while the event handler is called `rptCategories_OnItemDataBound` (no _Inner_) so I thougt it might be a copy paste error. If you put a break point in the method and check what the `sender` argument is, does it point to the `rptInnerCategories` object?

Comment: @user1429080 Good eye. This is someone elses code, i guess they forgot to rename the ID, but functionally, it's the same.

Comment: We don't know which method/event handler the code behind is in, it sounds like it's the wrong one to me. Do you find anything with FindControl, or are all those objects null?

Comment: @Janzi I can find the other controls within `liCategory` find by using the standard way of selecting them with `FindControl(ID)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem IS that you are using the same method for different repeaters.

In you last update you posted the whole markup and code, and if you search through the markup you can find the `rptCategories_OnItemDataBound` used on several repeaters:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCategories" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCategories_OnItemDataBound">
```

and

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInnerCategories" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCategories_OnItemDataBound">
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation of FindControl() method on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx), it only finds a control if it's a **direct** child of an element you're searching in.

This is not true in your case and that's why you can't find the control this way. You should find `liCategory`, then `lnkCategory` and then `pnlSubCategories`.

So, try this code:

```
Control liElement = (Control)e.Item.FindControl("liCategory");
Panel pnlSubCategories = (Panel)liElement .FindControl("pnlSubCategories");
```

**EDIT**

I've corrected the code snippet, it should be ok now :).

Alternatively, you can write a recursive version of the `FindControl()` method and use it instead. However, this should be rather used when you want the solution to be independent from the page structure. You can find some sample implementation of this kind of recursive method here: http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/05/06/asp.net-recursive-findcontrol-amp-extension-methods.aspx.

Comment: I'll try this but without the hpyerlinkElement as the Panel is not contained within that.

Comment: Didn't work. I think I've already tried this. I'm not doubting you here but if `it only finds a control if it's a direct child of an element you're searching in.` is true, then why is it able to find the other controls within `liCategory` such as `imgMan` etc... ?

Comment: I copied your markup and was able to find the `Panel` this way in `rptCategories_OnItemDataBound` method. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Yes. As to FindControl non-recursive behaviour, I think I've already seen this being an issue. What's more interesting in your case is that even your code behind finds this `Panel` in a sample app I made. In `rptCategories_OnItemDataBound` add first line: `String parentID = (sender as Control).ID;` put breakpoint and make sure it's `rptInnerCategories` in the case you're getting this error.

Comment: I've edited my post with pastebin links to the full code behind and markup

Comment: `rptCategories_OnItemDataBound` is used for both `rptCategories` and `rptInnerCategories`. This is probably the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Panel pnlSubCategories = (Panel)liCategory.FindControl("pnlSubCategories");
```

Comment: I don't think it's that. I set it to true earlier and it made no difference. Plus I have other panels on this page which have the same properties but are found fine. Adding the check for null will solve the error but won't actually find the control which is what I want to do.

Comment: As far as I know, the visible-property doesn't affect the code behind... It's only the markup code that won't be rendered if visible is set to false.